# Complicated array to excel in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have  two tables which I want to join and create an Excel .

**event_invoice**

columns

```
id
name
invoice_value
invoice_date
```

**`invoice`** model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    //
     protected $table = 'event_invoice';
     protected $primaryKey = 'Id';

    /*
     * An invoice can has many payments 
     *
     */

    public function duedates(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\invoiceduedates');
    }

}
```

**invoiceduedate**
columns

```
id
invoice_id
date
amountin
```

**duedatemodel**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class invoiceduedates extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'invoiceduedates';


}
```

So one invoice can have many duedates

I want to display in excel in this format

```
| name | invoice_value | invoice_date | due date1  | due amount1 | due date2  | due amount2 | due date3  | due amount3 |
|------|---------------|--------------|------------|-------------|------------|-------------|------------|-------------|
| A    | 5000          | 30-01-2016   | 15-01-2016 | 2500        | 30-01-2016 | 04-11-1906  | null       | null        |
| B    | 8000          | 02-05-2016   | 15-02-2016 | 8000        | null       | null        | null       | null        |
| C    | 10000         | 03-05-2016   | 15-05-2016 | 5000        | 19-05-2016 | 2500        | 19-05-2016 | 2500        |
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with Laravel, just basic looping and writing out lines to a file.  With that said, I'd recommend writing a csv file.

Comment: You can use this Laravel package to do the work **maatwebsite/excel** http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related with Laravel itself.

What you want to do is to use a library that allows you to manipulate excel files, such as [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) that you can add to your Laravel project using Composer.

From this point on, you just have to gather your data and write them in the excel file :

```
$invoices = Invoice::with('duedates')->get();

foreach ($invoices as $invoice)
{
    // ... Write the basic fields such as "name" or "invoice_value"

    $dueDateCount = 0;
    foreach ($invoice->duedates as $dueDate)
    {
        // ... Write the specific invoice dates using $dueDateCount to specify the ID

        $dueDateCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually When I do `$invoices = Invoice::with('duedates')->get();` i get the details of invoices but the relations are not showing it just shows ... there

Comment: Is it probably related to your `var_dump` configuration not having enough depth allowed